# Parenthesized Expression (Infix and Post fix) Conversion and Evaluation

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-operator, infix-operator

I have the below code working fine but outputs only 2nd input, not 1st or 3rd.
My code should get fully parenthesized expression from console and convert it to postfix expression and then that postfix expression should be evaluated in modulo 10.Therefore, all results (including intermediate results) are single decimal digits in {0, 1, …, 9}. I need to store only single digits in the stack.

My inputs and outputs are shown in below.I only got 2nd input correctly.

Please advise.

```
Expression 1: (((2+(5^2))+7) 

Answer: 
252^+7+

4 in modulo 10

Expression 2: ((((2+5)*7)+((9*3)*2))^2)

Answer: 
25+7*93*2*+2^

9 in modulo 10

Expression 3: ((((2*3)*(4*6))*7)+(((7+8)+9)*((2+4)*((7+8)+9))))

Answer: 
23*46*7*789++24+78+9+**+

4 in modulo 10
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class STACK {
private:
   char *s;
   int N;
public:
   STACK(int maxN) {
       s = new char[maxN];
       N = 0;
   }
   int empty() const {
       return N == 0;
   }
   void push(char item) {
       s[N++] = item;
   }
   char pop() {
       return s[--N];
   }
};

int main() {
   string infixExpr;
   string postfixExpr = "";
   cout << "Enter infix expression:" << endl;
   cin >> infixExpr;  //converting to postfix read from the input
   int N = infixExpr.size(); //strncpy(a, infixExpr.c_str(), N);
   STACK ops(N);
   char ch;
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       if (infixExpr[i] == ')')
       {
           ch = ops.pop();
           postfixExpr.push_back(ch);
       }
       if ((infixExpr[i] == '+') || (infixExpr[i] == '*')   || (infixExpr[i] == '^'))
           ops.push(infixExpr[i]);
       if ((infixExpr[i] >= '0') && (infixExpr[i] <= '9'))
       {
           //cout << infixExpr[i] << " ";
           postfixExpr.push_back(infixExpr[i]);
       }
   }
   cout <<"Answer :"<<endl;
   cout <<postfixExpr <<endl; //evaluate post fix expression
   N = postfixExpr.size();
   STACK save(N);
   int result;
   int num;
   int count = 0;
    string temp = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   //   cout << " Expr[i] " << postfixExpr[i] << endl;
       if (postfixExpr[i] == '+')
           save.push((save.pop() + save.pop()) % 10);
       if (postfixExpr[i] == '*')
           save.push((save.pop() * save.pop()) % 10);
       if (postfixExpr[i] == '^') {
           count = save.pop() - '0';
           num = save.pop() - '0'; //cout << result << "- " <<"-" <<count<<endl;
           result = 1;
           for(int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
           {
               result = result * num;
               result = result % 10;
           }
           stringstream convert;
           convert << result;//add the value of Number to the characters in the stream
           temp = convert.str();//set Result to the content of the stream
           save.push(temp[0]);
       }
       if ((postfixExpr[i] >= '0') && (postfixExpr[i] <= '9'))
       {
           save.push(postfixExpr[i]);
       }
   }
   cout << save.pop() <<" in module 10"<< endl;
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Off the top, expression 1 has more opening parentheses than it has closing ones

Comment: There is no attempt here to handle operator precedence. Throw it all away and look up Dijkstra's Shunting-yard algorithm or recursive-descent expression parsing.

Comment: In the evaluation part, you are doing math on ASCII codes of characters `'0'` through `'9'` (that is, numbers 48 through 57), not on integers 0 through 9. Curiously, you know enough to do `save.pop() - '0'` sometimes - why not all the time?

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that. Not only are you inconsistent in how you pop from the stack, but also in what you push onto the stack. Sometimes it's a character (`save.push(postfixExpr[i])`), and other times it's a number ( `save.push((save.pop() + save.pop()) % 10)` ). Figure out which way you want it, then stick with it throughout.

Comment: @EJP This **is** the shunting yard algorithm. As to operator precedence, the OP did mention the program expects a fully parenthesized expression.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, it is **not** the shunting-yard algorithm. No table of operator precedences, and no *other* attempt to handle that either. And if it really was the shunting-yard algorithm it would not exhibit any of the other problems you described.

Comment: @EJP You don't need to worry about operator precedence if you can assume the expression is fully parenthesized; you can then optimize away that part of the algorithm. The problems I described are in the part of the program that evaluates the postfix expression, not the part that builds it via shunting yard algorithm (which looks OK to me).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But it still isn't the shunting-yard algorithm. If the OP can really assume full parenthesization, it doesn't have to be, but it isn't.